# Android My application works on 2.3 fine but doesn't start even on 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How can I fix problems on Ice Cream Sandwich? also I am not good at reading logcat If anyone can guide me about how to read the actual problem on which line of my code I will be appreciate it..

stucks on :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

LogCAT :

```
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ko.tb/ko.tb.KOActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at ko.tb.KOActivity.onCreate(KOActivity.java:128)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    ... 11 more
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    ... 28 more
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:767)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2760)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:113)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    ... 31 more
```

Sorry for messy main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1" android:background="@drawable/back" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/loading" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/Reklam">
           <Button android:id="@+id/ReklamClick" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:onClick="ReklamClick" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/ma1"></Button>                 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:visibility="gone" android:background="@drawable/back" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/Giris">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

        <ImageView android:visibility="visible" android:id="@+id/betatesting" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="89dp" android:layout_height="89dp" android:background="@drawable/betatesting"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:visibility="invisible" android:id="@+id/update" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="89dp" android:layout_height="89dp" android:background="@drawable/update"></ImageView>

        <TableLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="85dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_height="70dp" android:layout_width="306dp">
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Logo" android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/logo1" android:layout_height="47dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="306dp"></ImageView>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="30dp">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Start" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="102dp" android:onClick="StartGame" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/baslabutton"></Button>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout2" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="30dp">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Skorlar" android:onClick="Scorelist" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="148dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/skorlar1"></Button>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout4" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="30dp">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/ayarlar" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="125dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:onClick="Ayarlar" android:background="@drawable/ayarlar"></Button>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
                <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout5" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="30dp">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Close" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="102dp" android:onClick="CloseGame" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/cikis1"></Button>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
         </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:visibility="gone" android:background="@drawable/back22" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="0.1" android:id="@+id/GameScreen">
        <TableLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/kelimeoyunubg1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/oyunlogo" android:layout_width="285dp" android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/oyunlogo" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="50dp"></ImageView>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/CevapBg" android:layout_width="281dp" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" android:background="@drawable/cevapbg" android:layout_height="93dp"></ImageView>
                    <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="139dp" android:id="@+id/CvpText" android:layout_width="133dp" android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible"></EditText>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/CvpTamam" android:layout_marginLeft="287dp" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="96dp" android:layout_marginTop="17dp" android:onClick="CvpTamamClick" android:layout_height="41dp" android:background="@drawable/tamambutton1"></Button>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/puanBG" android:layout_width="117dp" android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/puanbg" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="73dp"></ImageView>
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="85dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="44dp" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/HarfView7" android:layout_width="44dp" android:layout_marginLeft="310dp" android:background="@drawable/a1" android:layout_height="50dp" android:visibility="invisible"></ImageView>                            

                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/HarfView7mask" android:layout_width="44dp" android:layout_marginLeft="310dp" android:background="@drawable/ma1" android:layout_height="50dp"></ImageView>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/sureBG" android:layout_width="109dp" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/surebg" android:layout_height="60dp"></ImageView>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/soruBG" android:layout_width="453dp" android:layout_marginTop="133dp" android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/sorubg" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="103dp"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="105dp" android:layout_marginTop="340dp" android:id="@+id/Cevap" android:layout_height="103dp"></TextView>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/btnharfAl" android:background="@drawable/harfalbutton1" android:layout_marginLeft="340dp" android:layout_width="163dp" android:layout_marginTop="240dp" android:onClick="HarfAlClick" android:layout_height="42dp"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Pause" android:background="@drawable/cevaplabutton1" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_width="163dp" android:layout_marginTop="240dp" android:onClick="Pause" android:layout_height="42dp"></Button>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/SoruPuan" android:textSize="20sp" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/TotalPuan" android:textSize="20sp" android:paddingTop="35dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/totalTime" android:textSize="36sp" android:paddingTop="3dp" android:paddingRight="4dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="66dp"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/Soru" android:textSize="17sp" android:layout_marginLeft="27dp" android:layout_width="385dp" android:layout_marginTop="155dp" android:layout_height="67dp"></TextView>

                    <Button android:id="@+id/Se" android:background="@drawable/sb" android:layout_marginRight="80dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:onClick="Se" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Ce" android:background="@drawable/cb" android:layout_marginRight="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:onClick="Ce" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Oe" android:background="@drawable/ob" android:layout_marginRight="0dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:onClick="Oe" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Ue" android:background="@drawable/ub" android:layout_marginRight="80dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="60dp" android:onClick="Ue" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Ge" android:background="@drawable/gb" android:layout_marginRight="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="60dp" android:onClick="Ge" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Ie" android:background="@drawable/ib" android:layout_marginRight="0dp" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="60dp" android:onClick="Ie" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>   
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:visibility="gone" android:background="@drawable/back" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/Bitti" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TableRow android:layout_height="85dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="306dp" android:layout_height="70dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="47dp" android:id="@+id/Logo" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="306dp" android:background="@drawable/logo1" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/Logo" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="201dp" android:background="@drawable/oyunbitti1" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
                    <ImageView android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/Logo" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="77dp" android:background="@drawable/skor" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>

                    <ImageView android:layout_height="28dp" android:id="@+id/skor1" android:layout_marginLeft="157dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp" android:layout_width="19dp" android:visibility="visible">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout4">
                    <Button android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:onClick="PlayAgain" android:id="@+id/PlayAgain" android:background="@drawable/yenioyunbutton" android:layout_width="125dp"></Button>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                    <Button android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:onClick="CloseGame" android:id="@+id/Close" android:background="@drawable/cikis1" android:layout_width="102dp"></Button>
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Scorelist" android:visibility="gone"  android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <Button android:layout_height="42dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="120dp" android:onClick="AnaMenu" android:id="@+id/MenuBack" android:background="@drawable/backbtn" android:layout_width="42dp"></Button>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Scorelistic"  android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/bestscore" android:layout_height="267dp" android:layout_width="432dp" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">

                <TableLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="85dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="349dp" android:layout_height="74dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="74dp" android:id="@+id/score1" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="349dp" android:background="@drawable/birincibg" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/birinci" android:textSize="16sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="348dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/score2" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:background="@drawable/ikinciscorebg" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/ikinci" android:textSize="10sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="17dp" android:id="@+id/score2sayi" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" android:layout_width="16dp" android:background="@drawable/skor2" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="348dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/score3" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:background="@drawable/ikinciscorebg" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/ucuncu" android:textSize="10sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="17dp" android:id="@+id/score3sayi" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" android:layout_width="16dp" android:background="@drawable/skor3" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="348dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/score4" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:background="@drawable/ikinciscorebg" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/dorduncu" android:textSize="10sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="17dp" android:id="@+id/score4sayi" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" android:layout_width="16dp" android:background="@drawable/skor4" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="348dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/score5" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:background="@drawable/ikinciscorebg" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/besinci" android:textSize="10sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
                            <ImageView android:layout_height="17dp" android:id="@+id/score5sayi" android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" android:layout_width="16dp" android:background="@drawable/skor5" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="348dp" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="348dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:id="@+id/frameLayout5">
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout> 
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Noureddine AMRI I added XML file but Its very messy and long sorry for that. also I had to cut some of code coz stackoverflow said that cant be more than 30000 but I cared which to delete so It wont be problem I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

> 12-18 11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950): Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 12-18 11:31:07.432:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) 12-18
>   11:31:07.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24950):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)

You are using too much memory. This could be just the last drop because of all the other stuff, and it could be just that you are loading too big an image.

Remember, you only have a limited amount of heap-space available. It used to be 16 megs, but there are handsets out there that grant you more. I wouldn't count on it though.

Comment: just checked my drawble total folder is 2.3 MB and I have 7 png file (175kb to 260kb range) and 15 png/jpg file (10kb to 75kb range) and some more small images.. how come possible I exceed 16MB limit?

Comment: You are not showing png's probably,you are showing bitmaps, that were created (in memory!) from those pngs: check out this line: `android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate`. Bitmaps get big, as they are just a compilation of "this pixels has this color. the next has this color" etc.

Comment: I just clear the all big png files and works fine now. but how can I use images on my game application. such as background or something less than 250kb png... how does the other game developers do? should I use bmp file rather than png?

Comment: That doesn't really matter, as the problem is with the reading of the bitmap. you can for instance make the images smaller in resolution, scale them when reading them with the options from `BitmapFactory.options` or use an alternative option (like image generation) to show the images. It all depens on what the images are for.

Comment: I just tried to understand what is using the memory much and as the image shows I am using %95 of memory but doesn't show what is using 17/21 MB of memory. I can see 3/21 MB memory what is using.. http://i7.photobucket.com/albums/y253/byjoker/heap.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond, I have no answer for you. The only advice I can give is stepping trough your code with the debugger and see if there is a leak, or when you get too much memory in use...

Answer (score 1):

Over 30000 lines in an XML layout?! No surprise that you have a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Try optimizing your layout.

Try using ListView, and put your table layouts in the list rows.

**EDIT:** Android XML layouts are not like html pages, the more you put in them the more ressources you take.

Comment: I don't know how to optimize my layout. I need that all stuff. It's a simple game actually, how the complex game developers manage their layout then? I don't have know how on this. also It works fine on 2.3 its strange.. pls guide me :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try to increase the heapsize by code,

try this post :
[Does Android's large heap option work for older phones upgraded to ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675037/does-androids-large-heap-option-work-for-older-phones-upgraded-to-ics)

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.